# Html5 Canvas, click on the image that is always above

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have created a 2d isometric map with canvas in HTML5.

For my tiles follow well I had overlay them.

So, after : `_tile.drawImage()`

When i try to :

```
_tile.on("click", function(e) {
    this.opacity = this.opacity < 1 ? 1 : 0.5 ;
});
```

I need to always click on the images on the top (z-index max). Actually, when i click, i always click on the image that is below...

Any ideas ? Thanks !

Comment: Which tiles library are you using?

Comment: I'm using canva engine.